# Netbeans 11 does not copy libs into dist folder

Tags: ant, java-11, netbeans-11

I want to have a lib folder with all dependent libraries in the dist folder when I create my Netbeans-Project (with Ant and java 11).

I have all my libs within the project at Libraries (you can see them at Project->Properties->Libraries under Classpath) and I also have the checkbox "Copy Dependent Libraries" at Project->Properties->Build->Packaging enabled

I thought the checkbox enables copylibs, but there is no lib folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a NetBeans 9.0-11.0 bug.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1097

There is a work-around in there.

Basically in your build-impl.xml file, delete this after `<condition property="do.mkdist">`:

```
 <not>
        <istrue value="${modules.supported.internal}"/>
 </not>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know, if this is the same bug, because it seams to be a problem with Netbeans 11. But your solution looks very similar to what I did: I set do.mkdist=true in the nbproject/private/private.properties. After that, everything worked as before.

Comment: Verified your solution: Works like a charm, and I think it's more nice then my hack. Thanks a lot trilogy!

Comment: Perhaps we should open an issue at Apache board if it's not opened yet?

Answer (score 2):

On one of my NetBeans 11 projects showed the same problem that in the dist folder no lib subfolder was created during build. The project was using JDK12. After i changed Project properties->Sources->Source/Binary Format to JDK8, the dist/lib folder was created and populated.